# Angular 5 Circular dependency detected warning

Tags: angular

Please tell me what am i doing wrong here, i have wasted an entire day trying several things to fix.

When importing a module from a different folder, here i am importing preview.module in `src/app/common/modules/modal/sum-modal/sum-modal.html`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <app-preview></app-preview>
    </div>
</div>
```

below is the error i get on running  ng serve
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\common\index.ts -> src\app\common\modules\index.ts -> src\app\common\modules\modal\modal.module.ts -> src\app\feature\common\card\preview\preview.module.ts -> src\app\common\index.ts

folder structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7H6C.png)

code for index.ts ( in `src/app/common`)
export * from './modules';

code for index.ts (`src/app/common/modules`)
export * from './modal/modal.module';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to read this is that:

A imports B which imports C which imports D and D imports A so therefore a circular dependency.

To fix it, in `preview.module.ts`:

```
// import { XYZ } from './src/app/common/index.ts';
import { XYZ } from './src/app/common/XYZ/XYZ.component;
```

I never import from barrel files (index.ts). It causes build errors and these circular dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well i resolved this by doing some refactoring and moving preview component/module to a different module and not under common modules.